# Graph modeling – saving data history

Tags: database-design, neo4j

I'm using neo4j and I have a requirement to save all property changes history, relationships and nodes.

How to model the data structure so i can get the data snapshot in a specific time?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Just to make it clear, my requirement is to be able to present a snapshot of the data at **any** given time (that rules out periodical snapshots).

Also, I should be able to present the data changes on a time line.

NOTE:
My data could get as big as millions of nodes and 10 millions of relationships.

Comment: how big is your graph, and you granular do the diffs need to be? there are different ways to do this, with different tradeoffs. You could clone the whole graph on write, or version nodes and rels individually, or save diffs a bit like GIT?

Answer (score 1):

there was a good talk at graphconnect about this topic, the slides might be a good starting point: http://www.slideshare.net/GraphConnect/1140-adopt-suvee-fluxgraph

Comment: This slides describe a product that does this. I want to model it myself. Also this product gives API in java while i'm using .net.